# How to combine sequential periods of monetary awards by rate and type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains sets of data like so (I've omitted a few fields):

```
DateStart       DateEnd       Rate       Code
----------------------------------------------
1/1/15          2/1/15        $300       TT
2/1/15          3/5/15        $300       TT
3/5/15          4/22/15       $250       TR
4/22/15         5/1/15        $300       TT
5/1/15          7/10/15       $300       TR
7/10/15         9/2/15        (null)     HIA
9/2/15          10/10/15      $250       TR
10/10/15        12/1/15       $250       TR
12/1/15         3/10/16       $250       PD
5/1/16          6/11/16       $250       PD
```

What I am attempting to do is to create a table-valued UDF that will give me a resultant table like so:

```
DateStart       DateEnd       Rate       Code
----------------------------------------------
1/1/15          3/5/15        $300       TT **COMBINED**
3/5/15          4/22/15       $250       TR
4/22/15         5/1/15        $300       TT
5/1/15          7/10/15       $300       TR
7/10/15         9/2/15        (null)     HIA
9/2/15          12/1/15       $250       TR **COMBINED**
12/1/15         3/10/16       $250       PD
5/1/16          6/11/16       $250       PD
```

The starred sections contain rows that were combined because they have BOTH (a) the same Rate and (b) the same Code AND (c) they are contiguous (i.e., the DateEnd of the previous row matches the DateStart of the next). Note that the last two rows were *not* combined because the code is different, same with the fourth and fifth rows.

The table is usually in order by DateStart from entry but this is not enforced and dates can be out of order.

My early attempts have only had partial success. My first attempt *almost* works but does not account for the (c) contiguous dates factor--and I suspect also it will not work when data was not entered in strict order by DateStart:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[tableAwardsGROUPED](@WCB nvarchar(255) = '?', @returnType nvarchar(50) = 'All', @separateCredit nvarchar(50) = 'Yes')
RETURNS table AS 
RETURN    
(
SELECT 
MAX(WCB) as WCB,
MIN(DateStart) as DateStart,
MAX(DateEnd) as DateEnd,
MAX(ISNULL(Rate,0)) as Rate,

FORMAT(MIN(DateStart),'M/d/yy') + ' to ' + FORMAT(MAX(DateEnd),'M/d/yy') + CASE WHEN(ISNULL(MAX(Rate),0) = 0) THEN ' ' + ISNULL(MAX(Code),dbo.getRateCode(MAX(WCB),ISNULL(MAX(Rate),0))) ELSE + ' $' + FORMAT(ISNULL(Rate,0),'#,##0.00') + ' ' + ISNULL(MAX(Code),dbo.getRateCode(MAX(WCB),ISNULL(MAX(Rate),0))) END + CASE WHEN(@separateCredit = 'Yes') THEN CASE WHEN(ISNULL(MAX(CAST(CreditYN as nvarchar(50))),0) = 1) THEN ', CREEMP' ELSE '' END ELSE '' END AS AwardSummary

FROM tblPayments

GROUP BY WCB, Rate, ISNULL(Code,dbo.getRateCode(WCB,ISNULL(Rate,0))),CASE WHEN(@separateCredit = 'Yes') THEN CreditYN END
```

This seems to produce the correct results *when* the records are entered in order and there are no gaps or intervening periods with different codes or rates.

My latest attempt was this, using a CTE to force the data to be ordered by DateStart:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[tableAwardsGROUPED](@WCB nvarchar(255) = '?', @returnType nvarchar(50) = 'All', @separateCredit nvarchar(50) = 'Yes')
RETURNS table AS 
RETURN
(
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT TOP 9999999
WCB,
DateStart,
DateEnd,
Code,
CreditYN,
ISNULL(Rate,0) as Rate
FROM tblPayments

WHERE ISNULL(DateStart,'') != '' AND ISNULL(DateEnd,'') != '' AND WCB = @WCB AND ISNULL(Code,dbo.getRateCode(WCB,ISNULL(Rate,0))) Like (CASE WHEN(@returnType = 'Total') THEN 'TT' ELSE '%' END)

ORDER BY WCB, DateStart
)

SELECT 
MAX(WCB) as WCB,
MIN(DateStart) as DateStart,
MAX(DateEnd) as DateEnd,
MAX(Rate,0) as Rate,

FORMAT(MIN(DateStart),'M/d/yy') + ' to ' + FORMAT(MAX(DateEnd),'M/d/yy') + CASE WHEN(ISNULL(MAX(Rate),0) = 0) THEN ' ' + ISNULL(MAX(Code),dbo.getRateCode(MAX(WCB),ISNULL(MAX(Rate),0))) ELSE + ' $' + FORMAT(ISNULL(Rate,0),'#,##0.00') + ' ' + ISNULL(MAX(Code),dbo.getRateCode(MAX(WCB),ISNULL(MAX(Rate),0))) END + CASE WHEN(@separateCredit = 'Yes') THEN CASE WHEN(ISNULL(MAX(CAST(CreditYN as nvarchar(50))),0) = 1) THEN ', CREEMP' ELSE '' END ELSE '' END AS AwardSummary

FROM CTE

GROUP BY WCB, Rate, ISNULL(Code,dbo.getRateCode(WCB,ISNULL(Rate,0))),CASE WHEN(@separateCredit = 'Yes') THEN CreditYN END
)
```

Unfortunately this produces a very strange result set that I don't completely understand.

I can create a function/sub in my Access Frontend to achieve the same result but at a performance cost and it would be great to implement this somehow directly in the MS-SQL database (which I believe runs at version 2008).

Thanks very much for any help you can provide!

EDIT: @Sagar_Shelke's last answer below with a few edits worked like a charm (answer below is edited, working version), much appreciated!

Comment: @j-m-french In your data can you have more than two rows in contiguous  manner ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, there can, and this is actually fairly common in the actual recordset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really pay much attention to alias and column data types. But this will give you expected result.

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE(DateStart  DATE,DateEnd  DATE,Rate VARCHAR(10),Code VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #TABLE

SELECT '1/1/15'   ,'2/1/15'    ,'$300' ,'TT'  UNION ALL
SELECT '2/1/15'   ,'3/5/15'    ,'$300' ,'TT'  UNION ALL
SELECT '3/5/15'   ,'4/22/15'   ,'$250' ,'TR'  UNION ALL
SELECT '4/22/15'  ,'5/1/15'    ,'$300' ,'TT'  UNION ALL
SELECT '5/1/15'   ,'7/10/15'   ,'$300' ,'TR'  UNION ALL
SELECT '7/10/15'  ,'9/2/15'    , null  ,'HIA' UNION ALL
SELECT '9/2/15'   ,'10/10/15'  ,'$250' ,'TR'  UNION ALL
SELECT '10/10/15' ,'12/1/15'   ,'$250' ,'TR'  UNION ALL
SELECT '12/1/15'  ,'3/10/16'   ,'$250' ,'PD'  UNION ALL
SELECT '5/1/16'   ,'6/11/16'   ,'$250' ,'PD'

;WITH T1
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateStart ) RN,*
    FROM #TABLE T2
    where not EXISTS
    (
       select *
       from #TABLE t3
       where  T3.DateEnd = T2.DateStart and T2.Rate = T3.Rate and T2.Code = T3.Code

    )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT T1.RN, T.*
    FROM T1 
    INNER JOIN #TABLE T ON T1.DateEnd = T.DateStart and T1.Rate = T.Rate and T1.Code = T.Code

)

SELECT RN,MIN(DateStart) DateStart, MAX(DateEnd) DateEnd, Rate, Code
FROM T1
GROUP BY RN, Rate, Code
ORDER BY RN
```

---

### Creating Function

You don't need temp table inside function I used that for demo the result. I guess your original table name is tblPayments. So I created function based on that.

```
CREATE FUNCTION tableAwardsGROUPED()
RETURNS  @rtnTable TABLE 
(
    DateStart  DATE,
    DateEnd  DATE,
    Rate VARCHAR(10),
    Code VARCHAR(10)
)
AS
BEGIN

    ;WITH T1
    AS
    (
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateStart ) RN,*
       FROM tblPayments T2
       where not EXISTS
       (
         select *
         from tblPayments t3
         where  T3.DateEnd = T2.DateStart and T2.Rate = T3.Rate and T2.Code = T3.Code

       )

       UNION ALL

       SELECT T1.RN, T.*
       FROM T1 
       INNER JOIN tblPayments T ON T1.DateEnd = T.DateStart and T1.Rate = T.Rate and T1.Code = T.Code

    )

    INSERT INTO @rtnTable
    SELECT MIN(DateStart) DateStart, MAX(DateEnd) DateEnd, Rate, Code
    FROM T1
    GROUP BY RN, Rate, Code
    ORDER BY RN

RETURN

END
GO
```

Executing function

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tableAwardsGROUPED()
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I tried using this but it was giving me a "Cannot access temporary tables from within a function" error. Also dumb question but where and how do I put the RETURN statement so that the resulting table is returned by the function?

Comment: @J.M.French you don't need temp table inside function that was only for demo. So I created function based on your original table name tblPayments. Please check

Comment: Thanks very much for your help @Sagar_Shelke, I edited my answer. Unfortunately it seems like the result set is not combining any rows but is otherwise correct in terms of order, etc. It might be because the actual function has a couple of input variables that are supposed to limit the result set to particular "cases" identified by the column "WCB"; I put that in the WHERE clause for T2 and T2 that you wrote. Thanks for all your input.

Comment: @J.M.French Please select the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Definitely will (I upvoted your answers but I'm too low rep for it to matter I guess). The last answer unfortunately doesn't work, it does produce a valid recordset but none of the rows are combined (see my comment and edited answer). Thanks very much for your help though, gotten me a lot closer.

Comment: The last edited answer worked! Kudos to @Sagar_Shelke for all the help.